# $36x^2-121y^2=49$ in standard conic form

Tags: number-theory

$$36x^2-121y^2=49$$
Show that this equation represents a conic in standard position,
and identify the type of conic.

Is the correct answer $\dfrac{x^2}{\left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{\left( \frac{1}{11} \right)^2}= 49$ then divide by $49$ to give $\dfrac{x^2}{\left( \frac{7}{6} \right)^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{\left( \frac{7}{11} \right)^2}=1$?

Thanks!

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I wanted to know if my answer was correct. to be put into the form x^2/a^2 -y^2/b^2=1

Answer (score 0):

yes it is the same as $$\frac{36}{49}x^2-\frac{121}{49}y^2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

"Standard position" for a conic section usually means that it is centered at the origin with its axes aligned along the $x$- and $y$-axes.  By re-expressing the given equation in the form ${x^2\over a^2}-{y^2\over b^2}=1$, you have presumably shown that the equation represents a *hyperbola* in standard position.

I say "presumably" only because I don't know exactly what your textbook or instructor requires of you.  (In any event, the main thing your solution is missing, I'd say, is the word "hyperbola.")

Comment: Yea i know its a hyperbola but i just wanted to ensure i had the correct a and b values